# SQL Server 2005 database to 2008 R2 migration issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-migration

Recently we migrated our SQL Server 2005 database to 2008 R2. After that we are facing lots of issues

1. A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) .
2. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
3. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) .

We removed all firewalls , added connect time out in connection string etc.. but issue is still pending. It will coming in randomly why this is happening? thanks

Comment: Do you experience the same problems if you use an IP address instead of a FQDN/domain/computer name? Can you connect to the server locally or is it not responding to local connections either?

Comment: yes ; we the same issue  with domain name / ip/ SQL instant name

Answer (score 2):

Some things to check:

- Are you sure the SQL Server service is running?
- If it is a named instance or on a port other than 1433, is the SQL Browser service running?
- Are TCP/IP and/or named pipes enabled under Start > Programs > SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager (highlight `Protocols for <instance name>`)?

Comment: Do you have any insight into what these messages mean? They sure sound specific but I get the feeling from types of questions they cause, that they are in pretty generic network errors.

Comment: @ConradFrix I am not a network guy at all - for the first two error messages I've seen this before when the network configuration was not optimal or plain wrong. I've also seen similar symptoms with a flaky domain controller that would periodically have fits and not respond to requests (this could explain the intermittent nature of the problem). The third error is clear cut - if you can't reach the SQL Server, you can't establish a connection. I should have stated in my answer that these checks will affect #3 only.

Comment: thanks for your time. 
yes SQL running and it fine.i can able to login **SQL Server Management Studio** using some other system.TCP/IP /name pipes are enabled.

Same application hosted in two different application servers (load balancing). Win server 2008 (64x)  is the application server OS. Db server also having win 2008 & ms sql 2008 R2. 

Our application is using  Microsoft practices enterpriselibrary data  for database accessing.

**Please tell me I need to install any software like MDAC?;this issue is not coming frequently;I think this will happen only more users are using our service**

Comment: @rook.... If this symptom is only occurring when many users are using the system, then I suspect you just have a very shoddy network possibly combined with underpowered hardware. Can you post the specs of the SQL Server (CPUs, RAM), size of the database, and the details of the network (e.g. 10MB, 100MB, gig).

Comment: **processor intel E5506 @ 2.13 2.13;
RAM 8 GB;
Windows 2008 R2 standard sp1 installed;

Mssql 2008 R2 (Sp1);**

application server and db server are in local network;

Comment: Ok, but what is the network speed? 10MB, 100MB, GB? How much data is going over the network when "more users are using your service"? Have you done any network monitoring at all?

Comment: we have 100 MB/ps speed; our data will not Exceed  more than 2MD